# Lead acid battery charging current dosent become zero

Tags: transistors, battery-charging, battery-operated, zener, lead-acid

Here I am charging a 6V 4.5Ah lead acid battery by using a 8V-10V LM317 input supply for the circuit.

I'm using the BD139 transistor to cut off and a 6.8V zener diode.
As the battery voltage reaches a specific value, the zener will [[when battery voltage is more][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTdGV.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTdGV.jpg) conduct and the base current doesn't flow, according to the simulation, but, practically, the base current dosen't become zero and the battery current is still flowing.

Am I not understanding this correctly, or are there any modifications required?
I have used a pot to adjust the cut off voltage, placed in series with the zener diode.
Why does the battery current not become zero, even though the zener is ON?[image: Simulation when battery voltage is less which is connected to emitter of transistor]

Comment: so the transistor is a darlington part. what else aren't you telling us.

Comment: there will always be current through the zener.

Comment: Yep how to make collector Ic zero?

Comment: @Jasen it's BD 139 power transistor

Comment: if that's a BD139 why is the base current so low?

Comment: @Jasen this simulation didn't have bd139 but practically I saw 10ma base current

Answer (score 0):

You are charging a 6V lead-acid battery. It has 3 cells of about 2.1V in series (in rest, fully charged). For the Ic of the transistor to be 0, Ib needs to be 0. Let's calculate your *minimum* battery voltage. Your zener has a tolerance, but let's assume it's excactly 6.8V. Put the potentiometer at 0 (basically take it out of the schematic) to get your minimum battery voltage:

6.8V on the base of the transistor. Ube @ very small Ib = about 0.6V, so your minimum battery voltage is 6.2V. During float charge, the cell Voltage is about 2.25V, so 3*2.25V = 6.75V for your battery. That's higher than the minimum 6.2V of your schematic, so the current should indeed go near 0 if you give it enough time. (Never completely 0, as you keep float-charging your battery).

Maybe you wired something incorrectly? Did you check the B, C and E of the transistor?

Now, all that to the side:

- You are charging the battery incorrectly. Take a look at [the battery university website](https://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/charging_the_lead_acid_battery) how you should charge a lead-acid battery. If you use this method, the life span of your battery will be limited.
- If your battery is near empty, it's voltage will be very low, and you will burn out your transistor (even with *infinite* heatsink it can only take about 10W max.@Ta=50C and 1.5A), or your power supply.
- If you put your potentiometer all the way up (1k), your battery voltage will be 7.3V. That gives you a max. cell voltage of 2.43V, and you will over charge your battery until it boils, and destroy it in the process. Possibly there is also a danger of explosion, as the gasses from the battery are explosive.

So sorry, but I wouldn't reccommend building this schematic in a real-world scenario.

Comment: I understood your concern with this circuit but take this scenario what if I set the pot series with zener with specific voltage so that it compensate Vbe and battery voltage such that transistor base current reduces In simple how to make Ib =0 thus Ic =0 (approx)